# How can I call PHP variables into an HTML element?

Tags: php, forms

I have a php file (`first.php`) that uses the html form element to call a another php file (`second.php`) to email the data it collects.  After the form is submitted this calls a `third.php` file to display an HTML formatted acknowledgement with a series of variable titles, such as "Subject:" together with the variable data, BUT no data appears. After the html section the `third.php` file displays a set of `echoes` of the variables and their data values, so all the files are working properly EXCEPT for that the `<p>Subject: <?php echo $variable;?> </p>` elements have no variable data in them though the data is there, as shown in the `echoes` at the bottom of the page.

```
second.php:

    $file = 'third.php';
    readfile($file);
    echo nl2br ("\n\Label: \n"). $variable;

    
third.php:

    <p>Subject: <?php echo $variable;?></p>
```

It should be working - as shown described here and e.g at https://www.w3resource.com/php-exercises/php-basic-exercise-3.php  The php and html validate with no errors.

**Edit (re comments below).**
I tried forcing a failure by omitting a closing tag from a statement in `third.php`, in order to receive an error message and get some clue, but the scripts ran just the same!  I looked at the result of a submitted form from `first.php` in FF Inspector. All `third.php` statements are shown commented out whereas the outputs of `second.php` statements are shown.  So, the question seems to remain: how come the `third.php` statements are being commented out? 
**edit 2**
Inserting the php echo statement of one of the variable into the html title tag of `third.php` results in the FF tab displaying the full php echo statement not it's value.
**** SOLVED ****
I understood Barmar's comment as saying that the `require()` was not "working",  but it was, so that was that.  Subsequently I've been struggling with the terminology around "writing" php files, in HTML and php, and had assumed that ALL php statements in php files would be *interpreted* (is that the right word?).  I didn't realise that `readfile()` didn't work in the same way as `include` does, even after reading the PHP manual, especially as it seemed to be doing just that - except for the "glitch".  The w3shools reference was just a blunder - we tend to see what we expect to see, and as I'd typed include and read() into a search engine ...  In the end though the penny softly fell to earth.  Out of options, I tried `include` ...  **The answer to my OP is that** while `require()` does *include* the specified file, any php statements contained in it are not interpreted.  And I've had the *answer* for 13 hours - I just couldn't see it.

Comment: `readfile()` doesn't execute PHP.

Comment: Use `include($file);` to execute the code in `third.php`

Comment: _“I tried forcing a failure by omitting a closing tag”_ - wrong kind of “failure” … This is referring to whether reading the actual file content failed (wrong path, or missing access permissions), it has nothing whatsoever to do with whether that file contained valid PHP code or not.

Comment: What makes you think that anything should work "as described here"? The linked tutorial does not mention `readfile` after all